# Possible to Define Overlapping Filter Sets Using a Parameter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a report that I want to be able to return different (overlapping) sets of data with a single parameter filter.  I originally started using a CASE statement until I realized that overlapping filter sets are problematic for CASE.

```
    WHERE
        (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = CASE WHEN (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('01')) THEN 'CR'
            WHEN (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('02','03','04','60','62','63')) THEN 'OP'
            WHEN (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('01','02','03','04','60','62','63')) THEN 'CROP'
            WHEN (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD NOT IN ('01','02') OR DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('06','07','08','09')) THEN 'CO'
            WHEN (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD NOT IN ('01')) THEN 'OPCO'
            ELSE 'ALL' END)
```

My most recent effort used the following (figuring that if any part of the statement evaluated as FALSE, the entire condition would be tossed out), but it's returning no rows at all.

Thoughts?

```
WHERE
        (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'CR' AND (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('01')))
        AND (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'OP' AND (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('02','03','04','60','62','63')))
        AND (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'CROP' AND (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD IN ('01','02','') AND DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('01','02','03','04','60','62','63')))
        AND (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'CO' AND (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.DEFERRAL_CD NOT IN ('01','02') OR DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('06','07','08','09')))
        AND (@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'COOP' AND (DM_IAM_D_ACT_ROOT.LCYCLE_CD IN ('02','03','04','60','62','63','06','07','08','09')))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `OR`? `@ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'CR' AND @ACT_INCL_STATUS = 'OP'` can never be true.

Comment: <FACEPALM>.  Indeed.  I really hate when I miss the obvious like that.  Thanks so much for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this -- with what is called a lookup table.  Consider if you had a table like this

```
V    P1   P2
'CR' '01' '01' 
'CR' '02' '01' 

'OP' '01' '02' 
'OP' '01' '03' 
'OP' '01' '04' 
'OP' '01' '60' 
'OP' '01' '62' 
'OP' '01' '63' 
'OP' '02' '02' 
'OP' '02' '03' 
'OP' '02' '04' 
'OP' '02' '60' 
'OP' '02' '62' 
'OP' '02' '63' 
'OP'  ''  '02' 
'OP'  ''  '03' 
'OP'  ''  '04' 
'OP'  ''  '60' 
'OP'  ''  '62' 
'OP'  ''  '63'
```

so now you can just join something like this

```
  SELECT COALESCE(Lookup.V,'ALL')
  FROM table
  LEFT JOIN lookup on lookup.p1 = DEFERRAL_CD and lookup.p2 = LCYCLE_CD
```